# What are some better way to say “without any exaggeration”?

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote a sentence:

> Without any exaggeration, this book is one of the most popular ones in Sweden.

Is there a better expression than "without exaggeration", it sounds too formal and not natural to me.

Comment: An alternative might be to say **without doubt**. If you wanted to rephrase it, you might say: **It's certain that.... There's no denying that.....To be sure, this.....** But these are just a few of many options.

Answer (score 1):

The word "literally" is an informal and commonly used word to express that something is to be taken as stated and not as an exaggeration.

> This book is literally one of the most popular ones in Sweden.

Using "literally" is less formal and less clear than "without any exaggeration," but it is more common in everyday speech.  Some clarity is lost because "literally" is also used in other contexts, sometimes just as an intensifier that doesn't actually change the meaning of the sentence.